# Mako Filter in Chameleon?

Tags: templates, pyramid, pylons, mako, chameleon

Is there any possibility to use template filters in Chameleon as I'm used to in Mako? In Mako one could do something like

```
${s | filter}
```

where `filter` is a function mapping strings to strings and Mako applied `filter` to `s` and outputs it (after escaping HTML entities). So one could easily do things like

```
${s | nl2br}
```

I'm aware that the Chameleon way of doing it is [Line Breaking in Chameleon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044331/line-breaking-in-chameleon#15045703). But I have more applications for this filters so I'm wondering if something similar is supported in Chameleon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. Do the processing in your view instead, or use python code in your TALES expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In Chameleon, the pipe operator (" | ") operator means try-except, instead of "apply filter".

But since the expression language is simply Python, it shouldn't be necessary with such syntactic sugar.

Also, Chameleon has an `import:` expression type that can help you import helper functions:

```
<div tal:define="h import: helpers">
  ...
  ${structure: h.nl2br(s)}
```

Note that if `nl2br` returned an object that implemented an `__html__()` method, Chameleon would call this method to produce the output, and you wouldn't need `structure:` to avoid the HTML-escape.

That said, it's true that Mako's filter operator sometimes makes for more readable template code.

Answer (score 0):

The Chameleon way is

```
${nl2br(s)}
```

I'm doing it like this

*views.py*

```
form helpers import nl2br
def my_view(request):
    return {
        'nl2br':nl2br,
    }
```

*template.pt*

```
${structure: nl2br(s)}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure but, this only works if I disable the encoding of htmlentities of Chameleon, right? This is not a good idea - at least in my situation :-/

Comment: add structure: if output is to be interpreted as html

Comment: just as a warning to later readers: adding structure to the output can imply a major security bug.